# Datastore Asynchronous Write Operation, not saving

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

trying to write data to my local datastore like:

```
drivingJson = json.loads(drivingdata)
    for data in drivingJson:
        keys = getKey()
        index = 1
        dataList = list()
        for nodeData in data:
            self.response.write(keys)
            self.response.write("<br>")
            lat = nodeData['lat']
            lng = nodeData['long']
            color = nodeData['color']
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(nodeData['timestamp'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
            saveDrivingData = DrivingObject(
                                            index = index,
                                            lat = float(lat),
                                            lng = float(lng),
                                            timestamp = timestamp,
                                            sessionKey = str(keys),
                                            color = int(color)
                                            )
            dataList.append(saveDrivingData)            
            index +=1

        ndb.put_multi_async(dataList)
```

this doesn't populate the datastore with any detail. But when i use

```
ndb.put_multi(dataList)
```

the datatstore populates well. How do I handle the asynchronous call. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put_multi_async returns a list of Future objects.
You need to call wait_any to make sure the put's complete before you return from the request.

Have a read about async all work has to complete before you return.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#using

All through the document it talks about waiting.